# How to multiply the different selected checkboxes text into textbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If i have 55 checkboxes with different text 1,2,3,4 and so on ....and a textbox where it display how many no. of checkboxes checked ..... i want to multiply the multiple selected checkbox text with how many checkboxes are checked in other textbox .....

i want to do this using vb.net, asp.net

Comment: This question makes very little sense.  Please revise it and state clearly what you want to accomplish, with examples if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Like cdhowie i'm a little confused with your question, but if I understand well it's seems pretty simple.
You must put (eventually dynamically generated, it's the same) all you checkboxes in a container like a placeholder, and in your code behind to loop through them and test which of them or checked. If one is, you take the associated text, convert it in int, and add it to your total.
Here is a very little sample in c# :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph" runat="server">
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb" runat="server" Text="3"/>    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="3"/>    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="3"/>    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Text="3"/>    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" Text="3"/>    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" Text="3"/>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />

</div>
</form>

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = 0;
        foreach (Control ctl in ph.Controls)
        {
            CheckBox cb = ctl as CheckBox;
            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {
                n += Convert.ToInt32(cb.Text);
            }

        }
        Response.Write(n);
    }
```

Of course, there is many other ways to do that, but this is one is easy to understand like you seem to be a beginner.

Comment: Thanks ricard..this is exactly what i want...Thanks Man !!

Comment: You're welcome! Don't hesitate to mark the answer as useful or to mark it has solved your problem, by clicking on the icons on left of the post.